# how to find name wallet with a btc adress

Tags: wallet, address

I sent Bitcoin from one address to another, but I no longer remember the name of the digital currency wallet.
Is there any way to find out its name using a Bitcoin address?
please help me

Answer (score 1):

On Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/`

On Windows: `%appdata%`

If any of the following folder are present, you need to download *that* wallet software:

- `Multibit`
- `Bitcoin` (Core)
- `Armory`
- `Electrum`